Private conversions
Chalom
Are private orthodox conversions are kosher according halacha ?
For exemple, I converted sincerely throught a private Beit Din headed by Rav Chaim Amsellem .
The Chief Rabbinate did not recognize the conversion and I had to convert a second time.
Which giyur is the Good one? When did I become full jewish?
Was the 2d giyur a real giyur ou lechumra?

You should ask this question to the beit din which converted you a second time. It is likely that the answer will vary according to the composition of the first beit din and your own behavior. This is not a question on which this site can be too helpful.

Sometimes requiring a conversion l'chumra is more about politics than anything else, and it's not something to take personally (though I recognize that's quite easy to say and hard to do)

I will add that the Beit Din allows me to change my hebrew name different that the one I choose for the first conversion. Os this mean that it is not a giyur lechumra? In general,  is it allowed to change the precedent hebrew name at a giyur lechumra?

Are private conversions kosher? Yes, if done correctly. Is every Beis Din going to recognize the conversion of every other Beis Din, even those who  they are not familiar with,  as being kosher? No. Rather than independently assess every Beis Din in the world, The Chief Rabbinate has an approved list of who they do recognize and know a conversion done there was done correctly. Were you to ask a member of The Chief Rabbinate if there are Beis Dins who are not on their approved list that do kosher conversions the answer would be yes

I would add that the Av Beit Din of this Beit Din of this Beit Din wrote a book called Zera Israel in which he wrote we can convert a non jew with a jewish father even he wants to keep a traditionnal religious lifestyle, that is why I think the Chief Rabbinate do not recognize his conversions. But in my case I had take on me sincerly Torah and mitsvot yoke so is that change anything if the Beit Din has not a good réputation as I see many other who convert throught it do not keep an orthodox lifestyle...

@חיים If the Bet Din is not valid, none of their conversions are valid, no matter how sincere the convert.

Yes I am agree but here there was orthodox rabbis. I will add that at the time of Shlomo Hamelech, his wives convert throught a private beit din (hedyotot) and Rambam wrote that theirs conversions were halachically kosher
